# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el tipo del item de un IList?

Tags: c#, reflexión

Tengo un método que recibe un `IList`. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el tipo de los items que están adentro de la `IList`?

```
public void MiMetodo(IList miLista)
{
}
```

Tengo una clase a la cual le puedes asociar una `IList`. También le puedes agregar una función `NuevoItem` para agregar nuevos items. Me gustaría poder agregar items con el constructor sin parámetros por defecto en caso que el usuario de mi clase no le asigne valor a la función `NuevoItem`.

Agrego un ejemplo, porque parece no he sido clara con mi pregunta.
Si recibo un `IList<Int32>`, quiero saber el tipo del item, es decir, necesito obtener el `Int32`.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el Tipo de los items que están adentro del `IList` que recibo por parámetro? Sabría hacerlo si tuviera un `IList<T>`, pero no puedo cambiar mi **API**, ya que podemos recibir cualquier tipo de colección, no sólo `IList<T>`. La única restricción, aunque no está enforzada por código, es que todos los items en la colecciones que recibimos son del mismo tipo.

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas hacer esto? La idea del `IList` es que no dependas de la implementación sino de la interfaz

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz - Si, es compatibilidad hacia atras, se supone que las personas deberian setear el metodo NuevoItem siempre, pero por si acaso agregamos comportamiento por default. No es codigo que haya creado yo y no puedo cambiar la API.

Comment: Creo que te entendí mal, lo que tu quieres es el tipo del item por ejemplo si el `IList` tiene un objeto de tipo `List<Int32>` la respuesta correcta sería `Int32`?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz - Exacto!

Comment: Abajo te he colocado mi respuesta devolviendo el tipo de los miembros de una `IList`

Comment: He actualizado mi [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/903/629) para mostrarte los distintos resultados que obtendrías dependiendo de cómo venga declarada la lista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si el tipo del objeto que le pasas a `miLista` es genérico, lo cual puedes comprobar con `miLista.GetType().IsGenericType` puedes obtener el tipo de item usando la propiedad `GenericTypeArguments`

```
Type tipo = miLista.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

En este caso `.GenericTypeArguments` devuelve un `Type[]`, donde el primer elemento será el `Type` que buscas.

En el caso de no ser genérico no se puede hablar propiamente de un ***tipo de elemento*** pues cada elemento en un arreglo no genérico puede ser cualquier `Object`.

En este caso puedes asumir lo que necesites por ejemplo:

- Si existe al menos un elemento, asumir el `Type` del primer elemento como tipo del `IList`

  `miLista[0].GetType();`
- Si existe al menos un elemento, recorrer el `IList` y si estas seguro que todos los elementos son del mismo tipo asumir que el tipo del primer elemento es el tipo del `IList`.

  `miLista[0].GetType();`
- Si hay varios elementos de diferentes tipos, asumir `Object`
- Si no hay elementos, no queda otra cosa que asumir `null`

Si quieres estar seguro de todos los casos posibles te puede servir este fragmento de código:

```
Type tipoDeItemDeLaLista;

var tipoLista = miLista.GetType();
if (tipoLista.IsGenericType)
{
    tipoDeItemDeLaLista = tipoLista.GenericTypeArguments[0];
}
else
{
    if (miLista.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("No se puede hablar de tipo de elemento si miLista esta vacía");
    }

    var tipoDelPrimerElemento = miLista[0].GetType();

    foreach (var elemento in miLista)
    {
        if (elemento.GetType() != tipoDelPrimerElemento)
        {
            throw new Exception("No se puede hablar de tipo de elemento si los tipos son diferentes entre sí");
        }
    }

    tipoDeItemDeLaLista = tipoDelPrimerElemento;
}
```

Comment: Esta solución asume que yo recibo una lista generica. Lo cual no necesariamente es cierto, puedo recibir cualquier cosa que implement IList. Agregue una nota a mi pregutna para que eso sea mas claro.

Comment: @Dzyann si la lista no es genérica cada elemento no tiene sentido hablar de tipo de elemento. En todo caso cada elemento puede ser cualquier tipo que herede de `Object` osea cualquier cosa

Comment: por eso aclare que todos los elementos deberian ser del mismo tipo. Mas alla de eso entiendo lo que dices.

Comment: Tu respuesta me parece la mejor. Me alegra ver que tantas personas respondieron tan rapido en SO en español. Lo postee en ingles primero, y aca pensando que iba a demorar mucho en tener respuesta. Solo le agregaria que podes saber si la lista es generica con `list.GetType().IsGenericType`. Si le agregas eso (por completitud) te acepto tu respuesta.

Comment: @Dzyann ya actualicé el código

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien necesitas conocer el tipo de la lista para poder agregar nuevos items en tiempo de ejecución por medio de Activator:

```
object nuevoItem = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo)
```

Y para eso necesitas conocer el tipo de objetos que trae tu lista; entonces necesitas obtener el tipo de la propiedad *Item* de la tu lista, en otras palabras:

```
type tipo = Objeto.GetProperty("Nombre_Propiedad_Lista").PropertyType.GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
```

En tu caso especifico sería algo así:

```
type tipo = miLista.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
```

**El ejemplo completo:**

```
    public class Carro{

        public string Marca { get;set; }

    }



    public static void Main()
    {


        List<Carro> _listaAutos1 = new List<Carro>();
        List<dynamic> _listaAutos2 = new List<dynamic>();
        List<object> _listaAutos3 = new List<object>();


        _listaAutos2.Add(new Carro() {Marca = "chevrolet"});
        _listaAutos2.Add(new Carro() {Marca = "mazda"});


        ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
        myAL.Add("Hello");
        myAL.Add("World");
        myAL.Add("!");


        //Obtienes el tipo de los objetos de la lista
        Type tipo1 = _listaAutos1.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
        Type tipo2 = _listaAutos2.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;   
        Type tipo3 = _listaAutos3.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;   

        Type tipoArray = myAL.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;



        if(tipo2.FullName == "System.Object" && _listaAutos2.Count > 0){
            tipo2 = _listaAutos2[0].GetType();
        }

        if(tipo3.FullName == "System.Object" && _listaAutos3.Count > 0){
            tipo3 = _listaAutos3[0].GetType();
        }


        Console.WriteLine(tipo1); //<-- List<Carro>();
        Console.WriteLine(tipo2); //<-- List<dynamic>();
        Console.WriteLine(tipo3); //<-- List<object>();
        Console.WriteLine(tipoArray);//<-- ArrayList

        /*
        Salida: 
        Program+Carro
        Program+Carro
        System.Object
        System.Object
        */      

}
```

**Link del jemplo en DotNetFiddle:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnTLcw

**Finalmente:**

Podrás conocer el tipo real de los item de tu lista siempre y cuando estos no sean del tipo Object.

Comment: Esto solo devuelve `System.Object` en caso la lista sea no genérica y no creo que sea lo esperado.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz corrigeme si me equivoco, pero el tipo esperado implementa *IList* que es la base para los *List<>*, ahora bien, como no puedes crear una instancia de una Interface y tampoco (que yo conozca) existe una clase *List* que puedas instanciar, sólo te queda utilizar la case que si puedes instanciar es decir la *IList<>* la cual te pide por obligación un parámetro de clase.

Ahora bien, si el usuario de la API asignó el tipo Object a la List<> es otro caso, y esa discusión no entra en este contexto, pues el señor sólo necesita conocer el tipo de la lista.

Comment: Disculpa no entendí tu comentario pero la clase que implementa IList y que no es genérica se llama [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz la clase *ArrayList* Implementa *IList*, que es una interface; la clase base *List* (que yo sepa) no existe, la más cercana es la List<t>.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con un simple

```
typeof();
```

importante el comentario de Carlos:

> La idea del IList es que no dependas de la implementación sino de la
>   interfaz.

Comment: `typeof` devuelve el tipo de la lista, no de los items adentro de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

> La unica restriccion, aunque no esta enforzada por codigo, es que
>   todos los items en la colecciones que recibimos son del mismo tipo.

**NO** necesitas *reflection* para lograrlo.

En ese caso, **estás apoyado por una regla de negocio**, bastará con esto para lograr tu objetivo:

### implementación

```
static Type GetIListType(IList list)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
    {
        return typeof(object);
        // o si prefieres generar una excepción
        //throw new InvalidOperationException("No es posible determinar el tipo de una lista vacia o nula");
    }
    else
    {
        return list[0].GetType();
    }
}
```

### full demo

Y la forma adecuada de usarlo puede ser como lo vez a continuación en este demo donde pruebo con varios tipos para asegurar todos los escenarios posibles

- Lista con custom objects
- Lista vacía
- Lista Nula
- Lista genérica

el código

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Dummy
        {
            public int DummInt { get; set; }
            public string DummStr { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listaDummy = new ArrayList() { new Dummy() };
            Console.WriteLine("Tipo lista Dummy: {0}", GetIListType(listaDummy));

            var listaVacia = new List<object>();
            Console.WriteLine("Tipo lista vacia: {0}", GetIListType(listaVacia));

            ArrayList listaNula = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Tipo lista nula: {0}", GetIListType(listaNula));

            var listaGenerica = new List<int>() { 3, 6, 9, 12 };
            Console.WriteLine("Tipo lista genérica: Int32 {0}", GetIListType(listaGenerica));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static Type GetIListType(IList list)
        {
            if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            {
                return typeof(object);
                // o si prefieres generar una excepción
                //throw new InvalidOperationException("No es posible determinar el tipo de una lista vacia o nula");
            }
            else
            {
                return list[0].GetType();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### output

```
Tipo lista Dummy: ConsoleApplication1.Program+Dummy
Tipo lista vacia: System.Object
Tipo lista nula: System.Object
Tipo lista genérica Int32: System.Int32
```

Comment: **"estás apoyado por una regla de negocio"** --- En mi opinion es bastante peligroso confiarse en reglas de negocio y no validar correctamente el código

Comment: No tomas en cuenta si el usuario desea poblar con items correspondientes al tipo de la misma, por ejemplo: 

Si le pasas una lista vacía del tipo List<Carro> y deseas poblar la misma con X instancias de Carro desde un proceso simplemente no podrás, pues estas dependiendo de que la lista siempre brinde por lo menos 1 valor.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Interesante opinión. La validación certera en este caso (y se escapa del scope de la pregunta) sería arrojar nuevamente una excepción si se verifica que no todos los miembros son del mismo tipo, pero este proceso es sumamente costoso pues crece en función del tamaño de la lista. De manera idónea el propio proceso de ingestión de datos debe validar su tipo para dar soporte a la regla de negocio.

Comment: @MatthewJoelRodríguezLlanos lo se, pero precisamente esa es la pregunta de arriba, necesitan definir el tipo de la lista *con base en cualquier elemento* que contenga, ya que la regla de negocio implica que todos los objetos son del mismo tipo. Si la lista no tiene elementos su tipo no es definible, partiendo de que hablamos de un `IList`